# Can Google track my site without Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, tracking

If my site doesn't install Google Analytics and I'm using the browser IE, not Chrome. Can Google track my sites? (collect data about how many visitors, pageviews, time on sites, bouce rate...) If yes, how Google did?

Anyone has some docs about this problem?

Comment: track "what" exactly?

Comment: What problem? Why don't you explain the actual situation? It'll help determine if maybe you're not even asking the right question. For example: Assuming you *don't* have GA installed(since you're asking), then where are you seeing something suggesting that Google is still collecting traffic data about your site?

Comment: @Su' It's no problem. I'm just curious and wonder how Google tracks sites without GA.

Answer (score 3):

The Short is answer is: Sort of...

The long answer is they track things partially, and not completely accurately.

They can see who's visiting your site from Google search results. They can track usage when other visitors check your site from any browser that uses Google's phishing protection.

As you can see, it's not all about you, but more about how your visitors check your site out.